# Jquery mobile best way to store and retrieve data?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm new on jqm and see a lot of stackoverflow articles but what is the best way to store, pass and retrieve data in JQM ? I don't find example on the jqm site.

Is better to use global object, local storage, ... ?

Comment: You question is too vague. What data? Do you have a server side Database? Are you storing just for the session or across sessions? Are all your jQM pages in one html file, or in multiple files?  The answer is most likely a combination of storage methods depending on each scenario...

Comment: I do not want to use a DB. All JQM pages in one html file. I'm going to use Cordova and JQM to create a simple todo app or resto app.

Comment: See https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/passing-parameters-between-pages-multi-page-model/ for passing parameters between pages. It is also no problem to use globals in a single page app. Use localStorage to persist items across sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ezanker

See jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/… for passing parameters between pages. It is also no problem to use globals in a single page app. Use localStorage to persist items across sessions.